# How to make text slowly change color on hover?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I want to make my text change color slowly like this:
http://trentwalton.com/2011/05/10/fit-to-scale/

Any Ideas?

Comment: CSS3 transitions and let it degrade gracefully.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

<kbd>**[Working FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/J6grS/1/)**</kbd>

You can do it with [CSS Transitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/):

```
a {
    color: lime;
    -webkit-transition: color 1s;
    -moz-transition:    color 1s;
    -ms-transition:     color 1s;
    -o-transition:      color 1s;
    transition:         color 1s;
}

a:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS Transitions..
See this:  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bCv54/)

```
a {
  color: #000000;
}
a:hover {
   color: #E24B3B;
}
ul a {
 -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
 -o-transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
 -ms-transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
 transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As said by @elclanrs or you can also use this.

```
$("selector").hover(function(){
    // your code to fade in or fade out ....
});
```

Comment: He didn't say he was using jQuery

Comment: @Alex : Yes you're right ...
I just gave him another option, if he wanna use.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
a {
  color: red;

-webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
 -o-transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
 -ms-transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
 transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
}
a:hover {
   color: blue;
}
```